# How to upload multiplle files from a folder to dropbox folder

Tags: curl, dropbox-api

I have a folder and inside that folder 4 files,I want to upload all files from this folder to dropbox folder.

How I can do this.?

Below is my code:

```
     $ch = curl_init();
     $TOKEN = "token";
     $url = 'https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/upload';
     $cron_log = site_url().'/foldername';

     $fp = fopen($cron_log, 'rb');
     $size=filesize($cron_log);

     curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
     curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, 1);              
     curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
     $headers = array();
     $headers[] = 'Content-Type:application/octet-stream';
     $headers[] = 'Dropbox-API-Arg:{"path":"/home/test/address_proof.pdf","mode":{".tag":"add"},"autorename":false,"mute":false}';
     $headers[] = "Authorization: Bearer ".$TOKEN;
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);  
     //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $cheaders);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PUT, true);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILE, $fp);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, $size);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

     $response = curl_exec($ch);  
     $droplist  = json_decode($response,true);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The /2/files/upload Dropbox API endpoint allows you to upload one file per call. If you need to upload multiple files, you'll need to call it multiple times. In your case, you'll need to call it 4 times to upload 4 files. Make sure you specify the relevant `Dropbox-API-Arg` value for each one. For example, that's where you specify the path where you want to upload the file.